# Setter Method Won't Assign Property

Tags: swift

My setter method won't set a right property. I'm trying to assign the Fahrenheit property to Celsius when you assign it.

```
    var fahrenheit: Float {

get {
    return (celsius * 1.8) + 32.0

    }

    set {

    fahrenheit = (fahrenheit - 32) / 1.8

    }
}
```

Why will not my setter method work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using `set {`, the variable name you should be using to access the value to be set is `newValue`.

```
fahrenheit = (fahrenheit - 32) / 1.8
```

should become

```
celsius = (newValue - 32) / 1.8
```

From the Swift documentation on [Computed Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID259), for the setter you can define the name of the new value by doing `set(newFahrenheit) {`, or you can use the 'Shorthand Setter Declaration' which is just `set {` as you're currently doing which defines the variable name to be `newValue`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're assigning to fahrenheit, not centigrade.

```
fahrenheit = ...
```

Should be:

```
celsius = ...
```

And presumably you have a celsius instance variable already.

Comment: @AmitNivedanKalra Maybe It's better to paste the complete class definition and related error message.